# Trying to create reflection effect using visual brush bound to a listbox as the fill (dynamicresource) of a rectangle,

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a resource keyed as 'listBoxVisualBrush'

and a list box named 'listBox' which has it's ItemsSource property bound to a datamodel's observable collection

I would like to create a reflection effect using a rectangle(for example) by setting the fill to be the 'listBoxVisualBrush' brush.

It doesn't work (It seems it takes a snapshot of the empty list, so nothing is being reflected. But when I use some data in design time, everything shows up well and the list is being reflected in the rectangle.

Does anybody have an idea?

Thanks, Mike

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing code, but it sounds like the `Visual` property on your `VisualBrush` is being set to a different `ListBox` than the one being reflected. You want to use the same `ListBox`, not a distinct one. Something like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <VisualBrush Visual="{Binding ElementName=listBox}"/>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```